# how make multiple redirection with command and fifo

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, redirection, fifo

I need to write a bash script in a linux machine with the follow redirection.

```
echo commands > cmd_receives_commands > fifo > awk_parser > tcp_socket
```

I verified that for the "tcp_socket" works the construct:

```
echo 3<> /dev/tcp/address/port
cmd >&3
echo 3<&-
```

For the rest of the script I tried this:

```
mkfifo fifo

./parser.awk <&4 > out
exec 4>fifo
exec 3> >(cmd1 >&4)

echo to_cmd1 >&3
echo end $(date +%s) >&4
exec 3<&-
exec 4<&-
```

but they doesn't work, because the file out isn't written.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `pipe` like most people do? E.g., `echo "this is a test \n this is only a test." | grep only | awk '{print $NF}'` would print out "test."

Comment: Multiple Redirections in Command. This is why Linux have |[ Pipes ]|

Comment: really there is a reason. in my example the step "cmd_receives_commands" is a proprietary command that, if run manually, returns a prompt. I also need to construct a loop for repete the same command (for monitoring) a lot of time and eventually intercept the output before the parser ( I thought with a tail in the fifo).

Comment: I finally understood my (big) fault. It's about fifo. Once readed the data are gone.